# Slight Career Advice Regarding Recruiter on LinkedIn For Software Engineering

Tags: interviewing, software-industry, recruitment, linkedin

I was wondering if anyone can help me out with a recruiter who contacted me yesterday on LinkedIn for a potential role. The problem is in my response I had a typo and before I got the chance to review my work I accidentally hit send. I'm really upset that happened and am really worried about how I can move forward with this.

Having a typo in my response makes me look unprofessional (especially since this was for a software engineering role) and I fear the recruiter has judged against me based on that. Also, the recruiter had contacted me at 8 AM but since I have been having a stressful week, I have been sleeping late and waking up late. My response came in around 1.30 - 2.00 PM

I am very grateful for any help on this. Thank you.

====== **EDIT** ======

The question [Should I send an email correcting my spelling mistake in a job application](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/should-i-send-an-email-correcting-my-spelling-mistake-in-a-job-application) does not answer my question for two reasons.

The first is, my reply came in 6 hours later after the recruiter contacted me. For a simple yes response, should the wait time be that long?

Secondly, the typo was kind of a big one. Instead of writing "might" an editing snafu on the computer made that "m". Seeing that the recruiter was praising me for my experience and knowledge on first contact, should a software engineer be not more careful as they have to be so when writing code? What would the recruiter think?

Comment: @gnat Thank you for providing the link. While the question has some similarities to my concern, there are a few important differences. The first is, my reply came in 6 hours later. For a simple yes response, should the wait time be that long? Also, the typo was kind of a big one. Instead of writing "might" an editing snafu on the computer made that "m". Seeing that the recruiter was praising me for my experience and knowledge on first contact, should a software engineer be not more careful as they have to be so when writing code? What would the recruiter think? I haven't heard back yet.

Comment: For those downvoting, can you please clarify what is your major point of disagreement? On what grounds is this question lacking or inappropriate for this SE?

Comment: How does the typo make it look unprofessional "especially for a software engineering role"? In software engineering does the compiler tell you, that there's an error.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler Because that's a careless mistake. And this industry has no place for people who make careless mistakes. Especially for something so simple as this. An engineer who makes careless mistakes becomes a liability faster than he can type.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler The compiler picks up mistakes in syntax yes, but it doesn't pick up mistakes in logic. So if you wrote a syntactically correct program which can run in an infinite loop, taking up infinite memory, the computer will happily do so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMO, you're making much ado about nothing.

First, as to your response time - You're not on the recruiters time clock or payroll. He/She doesn't know what your schedule is like. He/She doesn't even know if they sent the email to a valid address. He/She is probably happy just to have gotten a response. The recruiter is a stranger, reaching out to you unsolicited. You owe them nothing. Reply at your convenience.

Second, as to your typo - It happens. People make mistakes. If I were the recruiter I wouldn't give it a moment's thought, if I noticed it at all. You're not applying for the CEO job at Amazon, so don't fret about it.

Comment: Agreed. If typos were enough to keep recruiters away, everybody would reply back to those annoying Amazon recruiters with typo laced emails, so that they stop. Alas, a typo is not nearly enough to ward off recruiters.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving a detailed reply to my question. I think what you mention makes much sense to me. Maybe I am overreacting. I just tend to get nervous when I make a mistake which I feel can be avoided. The fact that the recruiter has still not reached back after showing so much interest only makes it easier for me to fret. Maybe I will just wait and see how it goes for the next two business days. I'm thinking if I don't get a reply, I will just ask for an update. I will mark your answer as accepted.